# Select not selecting the correct option using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code sample displays properly but does not select the correct option:

```
<select name="number" ng-model="subscribe.number" ng-required="true">
   <option ng-repeat="i in createArrayFromNumber(event.free) track by $index" value="{{ $index + 1 }}">{{ $index + 1 }}</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vqavpk1/) to reproduce.

ng-model is supposed to select the correct option or am I supposed to set a `selected` attribute in the `<option>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use `ng-selected` construct.
For example:

```
<option ng-selected="{{ condition_for_marking_this_item_as_selected }}" ng-repeat=... >
```

Comment: That's odd. So the ng-model here is only bound one way? (only receiving value from select but not setting it?)

Comment: That's true. Angular does not check ng-model value (which could be something else than a literal) to "select" option.